Unimodality of distribution from Lévy symbol
Also posted in MSE.

Assume that one want to study a distribution $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for which the Lévy symboln, i.e.:
$$
\forall u\in\mathbb{R},\quad\psi(u) := \log \mathbb{E}\left[e^{iuX}\right]
$$
is known (
where $X$ has density $f$). In addition, suppose that one know that:
$$
\forall u\in\mathbb{R},\quad\psi(u) = \int_\mathbb{R}(e^{iux}-1)\frac{k(x)}{x}dx.
$$
I would like to know if there is a way to determine wether the density $f$ is unimodal from the function $k$.
Do you have any answers/references to this topic (or related one) ?
Thank you very much!
